# Count number of characters to print in x64 assembly

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I've been studying [this nasm code](https://gist.github.com/kindlychung/7d353b3e44d38561438c7bee0c33270d#file-sum-asm-L112), it's a toy program that adds two numbers from commandline args and print the result.

```
section .data
    SYS_WRITE  equ 1
    STD_OUT    equ 1
    SYS_EXIT   equ 60
    EXIT_CODE  equ 0
    NEW_LINE   db 0xa
    WRONG_ARGC db "Must be two command line argument", 0xa

section .text
    global _start


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Syscall args
;;
; As we can read in System V AMD64 ABI, the first six function arguments passed in registers. They are:

;     rdi - first argument
;     rsi - second argument
;     rdx - third argument
;     rcx - fourth argument
;     r8 - fifth argument
;     r9 - sixth

; Next arguments will be passed in stack. So if we have function like this:

; int foo(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6, int a7)
; {
;     return (a1 + a2 - a3 - a4 + a5 - a6) * a7;
; }

; Then first six arguments will be passed in registers, but 7 argument will be passed in stack.
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Commandline args
;;
; If we run application with command line arguments, all of their will be in stack after running in following order:

;     [rsp] - top of stack will contain arguments count.
;     [rsp + 8] - will contain argv[0]
;     [rsp + 16] - will contain argv[1]
;     and so on...
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

_start:
    pop rcx            ; first thing on the stack is n_args
    cmp rcx, 3         ; make sure that n_arg == 3
    jne argcError

    add rsp, 8         ; increment the stack pointer by a byte, skip argv[0], which is the program name
    pop rsi            ; get argv[1] address
    call str_to_int    ; convert argv[1] to int
    mov r10, rax       ; store the int in r10
    pop rsi            ; get argv[2] address
    call str_to_int    ; convert argv[2] to int
    mov r11, rax       ; store the int in r11
    add r10, r11       ; sum up

    mov rax, r10       ; store sum in rax
    xor r12, r12       ; set r12 to 0
    jmp int_to_str

argcError:
    ;; sys_write syscall
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    ;; file descritor, standard output
    mov rdi, STD_OUT
    ;; message address
    mov rsi, WRONG_ARGC
    ;; length of message
    mov rdx, 34
    ;; call write syscall
    syscall
    ;; exit from program
    jmp exit


str_to_int:
    xor rax, rax; ; set rax to 0
    mov rcx,  10 

; A loop for reading argc. For example if rsi points to ‘5’ ‘7’ ‘6’ ‘\000’ sequence, then will be following steps:
;     rax = 0
;     get first byte - 5 and put it to rbx
;     rax * 10 --> rax = 0 * 10
;     rax = rax + rbx = 0 + 5
;     Get second byte - 7 and put it to rbx
;     rax * 10 --> rax = 5 * 10 = 50
;     rax = rax + rbx = 50 + 7 = 57
;     and loop it while rsi is not \000
next:
    cmp [rsi], byte 0   ; check if argv[1] is null byte, if yes, return
    je return_str
    mov bl, [rsi]       ; copy argv[1] into register bl
    sub bl, 48          ; '0' to '9' in ascii is 48 to 57, so we need to subtract by 48
    mul rcx
    add rax, rbx
    inc rsi
    jmp next

return_str:
    ret

;;
;; Print number
;;
print:
    ;;;; calculate number length
    mov rax, 1
    mul r12 ; number of chars
    mov r12, 8 ; why? 8 bits each char?
    mul r12
    mov rdx, rax
    ;;;;

    ;;;; print sum
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, STD_OUT
    mov rsi, rsp
    ;; call sys_write
    syscall
    ;;

    ;; newline
    jmp printNewline

;;
;; Print number
;;
printNewline:
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, STD_OUT
    mov rsi, NEW_LINE
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    jmp exit

;;
;; Convert int to string
;;
int_to_str:
    ;; reminder from division
    mov rdx, 0
    ;; base
    mov rbx, 10
    ;; rax = rax / 10
    div rbx
    ;; add \0
    add rdx, 48
    ;; push reminder to stack
    push    rdx
    ;; increment number of chars
    inc r12
    ;; check factor with 0
    cmp rax, 0x0
    ;; loop again
    jne int_to_str
    ;; print result
    jmp print

;;
;; Exit from program
;;
exit:
    ;; syscall number
    mov rax, SYS_EXIT
    ;; exit code
    mov rdi, EXIT_CODE
    ;; call sys_exit
    syscall
```

Most of the code is straight forward, but I've been struggling with the part where it calculates the number of chars to print. It seems to me that the counting is already taken care of by L154, why does it need to be multiplied by 8 again in L112? Could anyone explain this a bit?

Thanks in advance.

---

- The code was copied from this blog post: https://0xax.github.io/asm_3/

Comment: It's broken. It clearly prints too many characters but if you are lucky the rest of them are nulls so you don't realize it. E.g. `write(1, "3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)          = 8`. It wants to print a single digit `3` but it prints an additional 7 null characters. PS: the `mov rax, 1; mul r12` already shows this is nonsensical code :)

Comment: Actually, I now vaguely understand why `r12 * 8` is needed. It must have something to do with how memory is laid out, probably whenever you push something on the stack, you will use an amount of memory which is a multiple of 8-bytes. I'll leave it to people who are more knowledgeable to give an answer.

Comment: @Jester I've tested this code many times with small and big numbers, it works as expected, at least on Linux. If I don't multiply by 8, it will just print 1 char.

Comment: @Jester Yeah, it should be `mov rax, r12` instead.

Comment: Yeah looks like it prints each digit with seven nulls because it used a silly algorithm. You just don't normally see those extra nulls in a terminal, but they are there. You can use strace, hexdump, wc or just redirecting to a file to see them. It's garbage code, don't use or copy it.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Thanks!